# Batch to read folder name and move to corresponding sub directory

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to create a batch file to help me automatically sort my folders into sub folders as follows:

As standard, the folders that I want sorted all come named in the following format

"(code) XXX NAME (Source) XXX"

//XXX represents random text that may be present.

// The first parenthesis is not always present either.

What I need is for the batch to read the text within the second parenthesis, which corresponds to the name of the source, and then check if there is already a folder with the name of that source and store the folder within the source folder (If there isnt a folder with the name of the source, create it)... This for every file present on the folder.

For example:
I have 2 files within a folder called "Animals", the first file called "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)" and the second one called "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)".

The idea is for the batch to get the "Carnivore" and "Herbivore", see if within the "Animals" folder there are folders called "Carnivore" and/or "Herbivore", create them if they are not present, and finally move the original files to the corresponding folder.

Is this at all doable? I've been reading on comparing strings on filenames but cant quite get it to work no matter what i try, though im not that much of an expert.

Edit:
I found code online and tried to adapt it to my needs, though i do not understand most of it, to be honest.

```
@echo off
:: setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set targetdir=DIRECTORY HERE
set setnum=0

for /D "delims=()" %%a in ('dir /b /o-n %targetdir%\*.tib') do set setnum=%%a
REM for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('dir /b %targetdir%\*.tib') do (
set setnum=%%i >> list.txt
goto loopexit
)
:loopexit
echo %setnum%
pause

REM for /D %%i in (*) do echo %%i >> list.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. (*I've been trying* without any code does not count as effort.) Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: I definetly would love to.. but i have nothing that actually helps, pasting every source ive read would not do either, I edited to include a code that i tried adapting from a kinda similar article i found googling, sorry if I offended in any way.

Answer (score 0):

> For example: I have 2 **folders** within a folder called "Animals",
> the first **folder** called "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)" and the second
> one called "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)".
>
> The idea is for the batch to get the "Carnivore" and "Herbivore", see if
> within the "Animals" folder there are folders called "Carnivore" and/or
> "Herbivore", create them if they are not present, and finally move the
> original files to the corresponding folder.

Just folders! This seems OK when files above are replaced with
**folders**. Bold text is replacements. I will follow the **folder** logic
with this revision of new code.
[Previous revision source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58b6851d-6753-4145-8666-4f30e3984141/view-source).

This script works in the current directory so it should work in the directory
of Animals. That is within the Animals folder.

The command `move` does not handle recursion though a cheap operation on the same
filesystem. You may need to use `xcopy` or `robocopy` if you have subfolders
within the folders to copy or move.

Created this code to use `move` or `robocopy`. The 1st reached `goto` decides
which to use. if both `goto`s are missng or commented the it will progress to
using the 1st, which is `move` and then goto the end-of-file.

Main script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Remove rem at start of next line to use 'move' instead of 'robocopy'.
rem goto :opt_move
goto :opt_robocopy


:opt_move

:: Handles copy of dirs to subdirs with last group name.
:: Works in the current directory.

for /d %%A in ("*") do (
    call :lastgroup "%%~A" && (
        if not exist "!lastgroup!" md "!lastgroup!"
        move /y "%%~A\*" "!lastgroup!" && rd "%%~A"
    )
)

goto :eof


:opt_robocopy

:: Works with files and subdirectories.

for /d %%A in ("*") do (
    call :lastgroup "%%~A" && (
        if not exist "!lastgroup!" md "!lastgroup!"
        robocopy /move /e "%%~A" "!lastgroup!"
    )
)

goto :eof


:: Get last group between '(' and ')'.
:: :lastgroup is called with argument of filename or dirname.
:: Requires last character to be ')'.

:lastgroup
set "lastgroup="
setlocal
    :: 1st arg set to variable str.
    set "str=%~1"
    :: Check variable str is not empty.
    if not defined str endlocal & exit /b 1
    :: Check for opening brace and closing brace.
    if "%str%"=="%str:(=%" endlocal & exit /b 1
    if "%str%"=="%str:)=%" endlocal & exit /b 1
    :loop
    :: Get remainder after 1st opening brace.
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=^(" %%A in ("%str%") do set "str=%%~B"
    :: Check for opening brace, loop if found.
    if not "%str%"=="%str:(=%" goto :loop
    :: Check last character is ')'.
    if not "%str:~-1%"==")" endlocal & exit /b 1
    :: Trim closing brace.
    set str=%str:~0,-1%
endlocal & set "lastgroup=%str%"
```

I used this unittest script in same directory as the main script to test with.

```
@echo off

:: Test environment in root of animals.

2>nul rd /s/q Carnivore
2>nul rd /s/q Herbivore
2>nul rd /s/q Fish
2>nul rd /s/q X20 X21 X23432
2>nul md Keepme
> "Keepme\test1.txt" type nul

if exist "(X20) Fox (Carnivore)" goto :next
md "(X20) Fox (Carnivore)"
>  "(X20) Fox (Carnivore)\test1.txt" type nul
>  "(X20) Fox (Carnivore)\test2.txt" type nul
:next

if exist "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)" goto :next
md "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)"
>  "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)\test3.txt" type nul
>  "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)\test4.txt" type nul
:next

if exist "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)" goto :next
md "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)"
>  "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)\test1.txt" type nul
>  "(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)\test2.txt" type nul
:next

if exist "(X20) (X21) Cod (Fish)" goto :next
md "(X20) (X21) Cod (Fish)"
>  "(X20) (X21) Cod (Fish)\test1.txt" type nul
>  "(X20) (X21) Cod (Fish)\test2.txt" type nul
:next

if exist "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)" goto :next
md "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)"
>  "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)\test1.txt" type nul
>  "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)\test2.txt" type nul
md "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)\subfolder"
>  "(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)\subfolder\test1.txt" type nul
:next
```

Tree after running unittest:

```
|   main.cmd
|   unittest.cmd
|
+---(X20) (X21) Cod (Fish)
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
+---(X20) Fox (Carnivore)
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
+---(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)
|   |   test1.txt
|   |   test2.txt
|   |
|   \---subfolder
|           test1.txt
|
+---(X21) Fox (Carnivore)
|       test3.txt
|       test4.txt
|
+---(X23432) Rabbit (Herbivore)
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
\---Keepme
        test1.txt
```

Tree after running robocopy:

```
|   main.cmd
|   unittest.cmd
|
+---Carnivore
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|       test3.txt
|       test4.txt
|
+---Fish
|   |   test1.txt
|   |   test2.txt
|   |
|   \---subfolder
|           test1.txt
|
+---Herbivore
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
\---Keepme
        test1.txt
```

Tree after running move:

```
|   main.cmd
|   unittest.cmd
|
+---(X21) (X22) Cod (Fish)
|   \---subfolder
|           test1.txt
|
+---Carnivore
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|       test3.txt
|       test4.txt
|
+---Fish
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
+---Herbivore
|       test1.txt
|       test2.txt
|
\---Keepme
        test1.txt
```

Running `move` will do a similar result as with `robocopy` though it will
not move the folder named subfolder. The unittest is run before each test.

Comment: Thank you for the explainations! definetly helps me understand the code a little better !, i just have one question though, i tried placing the bat on the animals folder and ran it, and nothing happened, then tried changing the targetdir on the code to the current directory route and nothing, am i missing something :/?

Comment: The script is beside the Animals folder. See the edit of the answer for overview of the file/folder structure tested with. `(X21) Fox (Carnivore)` is an extensionless file btw.

Comment: If you want the script to do current directory, change `set "targetdir=Animals"` to `set "targetdir=."` or to `set "targetdir=%cd%"`.

Comment: Just tested it!, that is almost what i wanted to learn how to do!

The problem that I have now is that that works on files, but if I have a folder called "(X21) Fox (Carnivore)", it does nothing to it, doesnt move it nor anything :/
It does work on extensionless files and files with extensions, but not on folders/directories.

Comment: Ive tried changing parameters using this article that i found (https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) but no luck so far.

Comment: You want folder handling as well. Sorry for misunderstanding your needs fully. I have updated the answer with file and folder handling.

Comment: no no, i only needed folder handling, the files inside the folders are ok left alone :D
Though this time i ran your new code, it created the carnivore folder, but it deleted the original (X21) Fox (Carnivore) for some reason, and when the folder Carnivore already exists it doesnt do anything

I tdont quite understand the new part of the code to modify it :(

Comment: I managed to get it to move the folder if the Carnivore one did not exist, by adding a line to the conditional here it is: if not exist "%targetdir%\%%B" (
   md "%%B"
            move /y "%%A" "%%B"

Comment: now the only problem im having is that, if Carnivore exists, it wont add the folders to it but it will delete them anyways.

Comment: actually after testing, the problem im finding is this: in either case it will only copy the first folder that has (Carnivore) but will delete everything else, regardless of which way in the conditional it went through, for example if I have (X21) Fox (Carnivore)\ and (X21) Dog (Carnivore)\ it only moves the Dog one to Carnivore but deletes both of them

Comment: I apologize for the amount of comments, this time i waited to try several things before spamming, so, by changing the xcopy line for this one: move "%%~A" "%targetdir%\%%B" it fixed everything so far.... now i only have to ignore any folder that may not follow that pattern because if a folder doesnt have a first parenthesis it doesnt work.... is there a way for the delimiter to grab the LAST parenthesis instead of the second instance of it?

Comment: Reworked answer with new code for just folder handling. Can grab text before the last parenthesis. It may resolve some issues you have mentioned by the use of robocopy.

Comment: you are a mad genius omg
I have learned a lot from you THANK YOU! not only did you give a superb answer, you gave me a way to research about the code used to actually learn, I gave you an upvote days ago but it says since i have low reputation it kinda doesnt count :c I modified a line on move to         move /y "%%~A" "!lastgroup!"
Thank you a lot for your time and effort I seriously cant express it enough.

Comment: Your welcome. If you [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then you can receive a couple of rep points and I will get some as well.